# tensorflow object detection API(Calculate Car speeds.)

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I used tensoflow object detection API to count the number of cars detected. But now i want to calculate the speed of all the cars detected. My question is is there any way to do this using tensorflow object detection API.

Comment: @user3232888: If you are detecting it on video, then you can let API detect frames at cetain frame rate. And then u will have the time & the distance convered (location point in pixels) & you can create the speed.

Comment: @beta i understand your comment. But what if in the next frame its not the same detected object.

Comment: You can use tracker. Opencv has tracker option. Once the object is detected track it.

Comment: Yes that was my question any method or pipeline that connects tensorflow object detection api with opencv for this functionality for tracking object with a uniqueID.

Comment: Yes.. Tracking can be done using opencv for each object individually. If u google it a bit you can get it. There's a car racing tracking example itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot Beta i got my answer now you can directly import tensorflow object detection models into opencv.

Answer (score 0):

You have keep track of the location of the cars with respect to pixels in intervals of time. You can start and stop the recording of time using 'time' library.

Also, if you are planning to calculate car speeds, you have to take the relative speed with respect to the camera movement. It would be easier if your camera is in a still position.