# How to only count an object once in a video stream? (tensorflow, CNN)

Tags: tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, object-detection, conv-neural-network

So I've come up against a little problem. Lets say I have a video of people crossing the road - in this example lets say the camera is looking perpendicular to the way people are walking across (they're walking directly horizontal relative to the camera).

Now from this footage I want to count the number of people that crossed the road.

The video stream is made up of 20FPS footage and my problem is that every frame my AI model evaluates it gives back X amount of people per frame (not really what I'm interested in).

So the question is, how do I evaluate an object passing through a series of frames instead of evaluating the existence of the object in any one particular frame?

One possible way I thought was perhaps when a new prediction of a person (say above 90% threshold) is made, assign it some unique identify and try to carry that unique identifier from frame to frame...

It seems like there's probably an easier way, anyone know?

Comment: You can find source code of the TensorFlow Object Counting API that is an open source framework built on top of TensorFlow that makes it easy to develop object counting systems: https://github.com/ahmetozlu/tensorflow_object_counting_api

Answer (score 1):

After doing more research I've come across another Stackoverflow question which is slighty related: [tensorflow object detection API(Calculate Car speeds.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48280680/tensorflow-object-detection-apicalculate-car-speeds)

It appears that OpenCV has a tracking capability. So perhaps I'll make an initial guess on frame squares, and then if over a certain threshold I'll advise to track.

For reference to further readers, there is a tracker called "Single Object Tracker" which combines a object detection model to first evaluate a square and then implements a style of tracker after that.